# Android. Ошибка при конвертации Set<String> в String[]

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь достать данные из `SharedPreference` всей пачкой по ключу, но не получается конвертнуть результат в `String[]`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set
```

```
String[] codeValues;
```

Делаю так:

```
private void loadCode() {
    preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> codes = preferences.getStringSet("codes", new HashSet<String>());

    codeValues = codes.toArray(new String[codes.size()]);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Пробовал так еще:

```
private void loadCode() {
    preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> codes = preferences.getStringSet("codes", new HashSet<String>() {
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            return false;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return null;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object[] toArray() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(Object o) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {

        }
    });

    codeValues = codes.toArray(new String[codes.size()]);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что у Вас в SharedPreference по этому ключу записан не сет, а что-то другое. Ошибка возникает, видимо, в момент [извлечения](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) сета.

Comment: да я уже сам понял, я записываю обычный `String`

Comment: @tCode тогда вам стоит принять ответ, если он верен